# Allow YouTube iFrame in Rails Application (saved in Textarea)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have a Rails model called Posts and I want my users to be able to embed a YouTube video in the content section of their post.

The post model has fields: title (string) and content (textarea).

Right now they can add the YouTube embed code (iframe tag) to their content; however, the iframe does not appear in the show view for the post.

Why is this and what can I do to display the embedded video?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it:

```
<%= simple_format(@post.content, {}, sanitize: false) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you missed adding .html_safe

```
<%= @post.iframe.html_safe %>
```